# How to list all default music players and open one

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

I want to click my music icon and let the user decide which music player they want to use, if google play music or another one they have installed

so far I have done this but it just launches the default google play music app

```
 try {
                    Intent intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Exception for launching music player "+e);
                }
```

Instead I was searching in all SO for this and cant find how to list all music players , select one and open it, any ideas ?

This is what I want to do

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set data type for your Intent:

```
public void openMusicPlayerChooser(File musicFile) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
        try {
            Method method = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            method.invoke(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(musicFile), "audio/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: the thing is that there is no musicFile as parameter to pass, since I dont want to open a specific song, just open different music players

Comment: with createChooser

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me**

```
Intent intent = Intent.makeMainSelectorActivity(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, Intent.CATEGORY_APP_MUSIC);
startActivity(intent);
```